# Php mysql query update of data gives syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, syntax-error

This is my php code to update products in database:

```php
$sql="UPDATE product SET name=$newname , price=$price , stock=$stock , color=$color WHERE id=$id";
if($conn->query($sql)){
    echo "product update";
}
```

It gives this error:

```
Error: UPDATE product SET name=samsung galaxy note 20 ultra , price=40000 , stock=5 , color=white WHERE id=1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'galaxy note 20 ultra , price=40000 , stock=5 , color=white WHERE id=1' at line 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```php
$sql="UPDATE product SET name='$newname', price='$price', stock='$stock', color='$color' WHERE id='$id';";
```

But a better approach would be to use parameterized prepared statements as you are vulnerable now to SQL injections. Also refer to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 1):

Put single quotes to variables which has string values like this

```
$sql="UPDATE product SET name='$newname' , price='$price' , stock=$stock , color='$color' WHERE id=$id";
```